# Xcode: Don't Expand Path Containing Symlink

Tags: xcode

All our dependencies are fetched or built with `bazel`. Bazel uses a `bazel-bin` symlink to point to its current build folder. Now I have a framework inside

```
<PROJECTROOT>/bazel-build/caa8aa98f5dcbb2daf59b2a104d45db7/execroot/__main__/
  bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/A.framework
```

which is shortened to

```
bazel-bin/external/A.framework
```

where `bazel-bin` is the current symlink to the build location.

Now if I were to drag a resource or framework into Xcode, it will automatically expand the path and use the absolute path for the framework.

How can I tell Xcode to keep the path with the symlink path intact?

PS: I have found that you can manually edit the path in your `.xcodeproj` file with a text editor, but I'd prefer a more robust approach.